# Missing "Enable standard Simantic Server Interface" in OPC UA server options of TIA Portal V16

Tags: plc, opc-ua, siemens, tia-portal

I'm pretty new to working on Siemens PLC (in my case a S7-1500). I want to set-up a OPC-UA server using a customn created information model. However I'm missing the option "Enable standard SIMATIC server interface" in the CPU settings.

This is how it looks like in the Siemens documentation which can be found [here](https://www.automation.siemens.com/sce-static/learning-training-documents/tia-portal/advanced-communication/sce-092-300-opc-ua-s7-1500-r1807-en.pdf)
[image]

However, this is how my settings look like:

[image]

Does anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong? Do I have to install or activate something to make this option appear?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nothing wrong except that the plc needs a newer firmware, screenshot shows that the plc is of firmware version less than 2.5.

Since your version of tia portal and the mlfb of the s7-1500 is unknown to me, that's the best I can do for now.